# Rails :dependent and :delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dependencies

I am running Rails 2.0.2 and am unable to use :dependent => :delete in my AR associations

```
 has_many :items, :dependent => :delete
```

I am given this error.

```
  The :dependent option expects either :destroy, :delete_all, or :nullify (:delete)
```

I have be unable to find the documentation for :delete_all to see if it does what I want. Is it basically the same thing as delete? Was :delete recently added to Rails and is not in the version I am using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the [relevant documentation for Rails 2.0.2](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.0.2/doc/index.html?a=M001413&name=has_many):

> if set to :destroy all the associated objects are destroyed
>   alongside this object by calling their
>   destroy method. If set to :delete_all
>   all associated objects are deleted
>   without calling their destroy method.
>   If set to :nullify all associated
>   objects’ foreign keys are set to NULL
>   without calling their save callbacks.

railsbrain.com is a good place to find docs specific to a certain version of Rails.

Answer (score 2):

Default action is "do nothing". Objects remain orphaned, nothing is deleted, destroyed or nullified.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention of :delete in the documentation of the current stable version 2.3.2:

> Objects will be in addition destroyed if they’re associated with :dependent => :destroy, and deleted if they’re associated with :dependent => :delete_all.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many